# TextDrawable sometimes not centering vertically when binding to a RecyclerView

Tags: android, text, drawable, vertical-alignment, centering

## Problem Solved:

TextPaint's setTextSize() should be called before TextPaint's descent() & ascend() as those two methods seem to depend on the text size for calculations.

```
@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
    Rect r = getBounds();

    float boundSize = Math.min(r.width(), r.height());
    float fontSize = Math.min(mFontSize, boundSize);
    mTextPaint.setTextSize(fontSize); // Should be before descent() & ascent()

    int originX = r.width() / 2;
    int originY = (int) ((r.height() / 2)
            - ((mTextPaint.descent() + mTextPaint.ascent()) / 2)) ;

    canvas.drawText(mText, originX, originY, mTextPaint);

}
```

---

[image: TextDrawables in a RecyclerView]

**Context:** I created a TextDrawable to turn strings into Drawables so I can set them as icons. I want them to be centered *both horizontally and vertically* when I assign them to an ImageView.

**Problem:** When I bind them to a RecyclerView, sometimes they center vertically but sometimes they don't (as you can see above). This can alternate as the items are rebinded each time I scroll through the RecyclerView.

---

I suspect the cause might be inside TextDrawable's draw() but I'm not sure how to fix it.

**TextDrawable:**

```
public class TextDrawable extends Drawable {

    private String mText;
    private Paint mTextPaint = new Paint();
    private float mFontSize = 48;

    public TextDrawable(String text) {
        mText = text;

        mTextPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        mTextPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mTextPaint.setFakeBoldText(false);
        mTextPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        mTextPaint.setTypeface(Typeface.create("sans-serif-light", Typeface.NORMAL));
        mTextPaint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
        mTextPaint.setStrokeWidth(0);
    }

    public void setFontSize(float fontSize) {
        mFontSize = fontSize;
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        Rect r = getBounds();

        int originX = r.width() / 2;
        int originY = (int) ((r.height() / 2)
                - ((mTextPaint.descent() + mTextPaint.ascent()) / 2)) ;

        float boundSize = Math.min(r.width(), r.height());
        float fontSize = Math.min(mFontSize, boundSize);
        mTextPaint.setTextSize(fontSize);

        canvas.drawText(mText, originX, originY, mTextPaint);

    }

    @Override
    public void setAlpha(int alpha) {
        mTextPaint.setAlpha(alpha);
    }

    @Override
    public void setColorFilter(ColorFilter colorFilter) {
        mTextPaint.setColorFilter(colorFilter);
    }

    @Override
    public int getOpacity() {
        return PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT;
    }
}
```

**Task's getIcon() Method:**

```
public Drawable getIcon() {
    String letter = mTitle.substring(0, 1);
    return new TextDrawable(letter);
}
```

**RecyclerView ViewHolder's bind() Method:**

```
void bind(Task task) {
    mCircleView.setImageDrawable(task.getIcon()); 
}
```

Comment: have you tried bounds.centerY()

Comment: I solved the problem. I should have called setTextSize() before calling descent() & ascent() because those two methods seem to depend on it for calculation.